# Is there a way to get the current number of kilobits being sent and received in Java?

Tags: java, network-programming, send

I am a programmer in Java, and I was wondering if there was a way to get the Send and Recieve on a specific computer. (In other words, get the number kilobits that are being received or being sent). If you are still confused, I am talking about this. (Highlighted in blue)

[Task Manager Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGcTY.png)

I have no idea where to start to extract this information. Does anyone have any ideas to help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Since you're apparently on Windows, you can query this information from [WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) and/or [Windows Performance Counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/perfctrs/performance-counters-portal).  You'll need to a) decide which (if either) meets your needs, then b) find a Java library

Comment: @FoggyDay Oh. I see. Do you know why someone downvoted my question though? I tried my best.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25035543/windows-performance-counters-from-java) and see if it meets your needs. It is a pain to code for win32 so I would try to avoid it